Reading Windows Registry HKLM Key from Maui App in sideloaded installation
My maui app needs to read a registry key from HKLM\SOFTWARE\company\product to find the full path to the executeable of an other installed program.
Screenshot of regedit
It works fine when the app is deployed from visual studio, but doesn't work if the app is pushlished, signed and manually installed (sideload).
A System.NullReferenceException is thrown when accessing the registry:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code for accessing the Registry item:
private async void StartSignation() {
#if WINDOWS
    try {
        string pathToExe = Registry.GetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\company\\product", null, null).ToString();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // Log this exception
    }
#endif
}

The code gets called from a TapGestureRecognizer:
<controls:LinkIconButton LabelText="read registry" Icon="registry.png">
    <controls:LinkIconButton.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </controls:LinkIconButton.GestureRecognizers>
</controls:LinkIconButton>

Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest contains this
<Capabilities>
  <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
</Capabilities>

How to access the registry at productive deployed release?

I can't reproduce your problem. I can read the key sucessfully after I published the project by the two ways in the official document about Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows. But I can't read the key in the native winui 3 project unless I add the Registry HKLM Key below the SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node.
